# MSVC Cmake project with SQLite dependency has linker error

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-c++, cmake

I have a cmake project with a sqlite ExternalProject. Sqlite *appears* to build correctly. I don't get any errors, and I get out a .dll and .lib (which I assume is the import library). But when the main project is built, it fails with a linker error:

```
2>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sqlite3_open referenced in function main [C:\Users\Public\Documents\my_proj\ExternalProjects\Build\main\main.vcxproj]
```

And many more like that for other symbols. I've googled around and the common answer is "make sure you're actually linking with the import library." But I'm pretty sure I'm doing that. The generated VS project links to the correct file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/56NNS.png), and the file really exists. But still... link error. Does anyone know why?

Reproducible source in a [git repo](https://gitlab.com/MoTTs_/cmake-sqlite-test.git) or posted below...

```
# my_proj/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

include(ExternalProject)
set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY EP_BASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProjects")

# Download and build sqlite
ExternalProject_Add(
    sqlite URL https://www.sqlite.org/snapshot/sqlite-snapshot-201710282054.tar.gz
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND nmake /f Makefile.msc
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(sqlite SOURCE_DIR)
set(SQLITE_SOURCE_DIR "${SOURCE_DIR}")

# Now that dependencies are ready,
# generate build script for our "real" project
ExternalProject_Add(
    main DEPENDS sqlite
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND "" SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${SQLITE_SOURCE_DIR}"
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

.

```
# my_proj/lib/CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

find_path(SQLITE_DIR sqlite3.h)
add_library(sqlite SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET sqlite PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${SQLITE_DIR}")
set_property(TARGET sqlite PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SQLITE_DIR}/sqlite3.dll")
set_property(TARGET sqlite PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${SQLITE_DIR}/sqlite3.lib")

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC sqlite)
```

.

```
// my_proj/lib/src/main.cpp
// sample program copy-pasted from https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  sqlite3 *db;
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  int rc;

  if( argc!=3 ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT\n", argv[0]);
    return(1);
  }
  rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
  if( rc ){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return(1);
  }
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT: Still troubleshooting. Here's some new info.

I've been digging into their Makefile.msc. First they compile their source to a library object file.

```
cl -nologo -W4 -DINCLUDE_MSVC_H=1   -DSQLITE_OS_WIN=1 -I. -I. -fp:precise -MT -DNDEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 -DSQLITE_THREAD_OVERRIDE_LOCK=-1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=1  -DSQLITE_MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH=100  -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1   -O2 -Zi -Fosqlite3.lo  -c sqlite3.c
```

Then they try to auto-generate a .def file by examining the output of dumpbin.

```
dumpbin /all sqlite3.lo
| .\Replace.exe "^\s+/EXPORT:_?(sqlite3...
```

There's more to that regular expression, but I truncated it for brevity. It doesn't match anything. In fact, I searched through the output of dumpbin, and even the word "EXPORT" doesn't appear anywhere. So... maybe dumpbin broke BC, changed their output, and no one on the Sqlite team noticed...? That feels a little hard to believe, but it's my best working theory for now. Tomorrow I'll try on an older MSVC with an older dumpbin and see if that makes a difference.

---

EDIT: MSVC 2013's dumpbin output doesn't contain the word "EXPORT" either. :-(

Comment: This just looks really weird.  You use external projects for, well, projects that are internal, not your own project.  Typical usage would be to add an external project for SQLite but not for your project.  What makes you want to do it this way?

Comment: @legalize Because the find_* commands run at configuration time (when you run `cmake`) but externalproject runs at build time (when you run `make`). Meaning it tries to find the dependencies *before* it has downloaded and built them. Splitting the cmake into two layers forces the order we want. More details: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-October/056105.html

Comment: Hey @JeffM, Did you ever find a solution? I'm getting multiple errors like this in my cmake build command. Please suggest.